# delete all duplicated nodes in unsorted linked list

Tags: c, struct, free, singly-linked-list, function-definition

the main purpose of my code is that to take a data from the user and then search the single linked list to find the target and then delete all the nodes that are equal to target.
this is also the base single linked list:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}no;
```

**Input:** 1, 2, 3, 2, 5 --> to delete= 2

so the new linked list is: 1, 3, 5

```
void* toDElduplicatedlinkedlist (no* firstNode, int target)
{

    no* current = firstNode;
    no* ptemp;

while ( NULL != current->next)
{


    if (firstNode->data == target)
    {
        current = firstNode->next;
        free(firstNode);

    }

    else if (current->next->data == target)
        {
            ptemp = current->next;
            current->next= current->next->next;
            free(ptemp);
        }

        current = current->next;

}
```

this is my to-delete function I wrote.
it works for the target items that are in the middle of the linked list but when the `firstNode` which is head of the list is the target it either doesn't deletes it or looses the head address and i tried to do many ways to save the head of the list so that it wont loose it.

it also doesn't work for the situation that the last node it the target.

I was struggling with this problem but i couldn't solve it so i would be happy and thankful if someone helps me with this.

Comment: You check the `firstNode` value on each iteration of the loop, even after the first node may be freed. You are probably getting a use-after-free error. There are also other design flaws as specified in @Vlad from Moscow's answer

Comment: oh i see point now. thank you @MichaelSohnen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function returns nothing though its return type is `void *`.

This while loop

```
while ( NULL != current->next)
```

can invoke undefined behavior if the function is called for an empty list.

Also the while loop is skipped when the list contains only one node.

Or for example if the first node contains a value that is equal to the parameter target then in the first iteration of the loop the pointed node will be freed. However in the next iteration of the loop you are again checking the deleted node

```
if (firstNode->data == target)
{
    current = firstNode->next;
    free(firstNode);

}
```

that one more invokes undefined behavior.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( no **firstNode, int target )
{
    while ( *firstNode )
    {
        if ( ( *firstNode )->data == target )
        {
            no *tmp = *firstNode;
            *firstNode = ( *firstNode )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            firstNode = &( *firstNode )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

And if in the caller of the function you have

```
no *firstNode;
```

then the function is called like

```
toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( &firstNode, target );
```

That is the pointer to the first node of the list is passed by reference.

Another way to define the function is the following

```
no * toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( no *firstNode, int target )
{
    while ( firstNode && firstNode->data == target )
    {
        no *tmp = firstNode;
        firstNode = firstNode->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    if ( firstNode != NULL )
    {
        for ( no *current = firstNode; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->next->data == target )
            {
                no *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
      
    return firstNode;
}
```

In this case the function is called like

```
firstNode = toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( firstNode, target );
```

And at last the function can be also defined the following way

```
no * toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( no *firstNode, int target )
{
    for ( no **current = &firstNode; *current; )
    {
        if ( ( *current )->data == target )
        {
            no *tmp = *current;
            *current = ( *current )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return firstNode;
}
```

and called the same way as shown above that is

```
firstNode = toDElduplicatedlinkedlist( firstNode, target );
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how does this code not inadvertently move the head of the list to its tail? Why do we not need to save a copy of `firstNode`? Is this solved by the extra level of indirection?

Comment: @MichaelSohnen It is the pointer to pointer that is moved to the tail of the list.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. here I have a question, the `no **firstNode` is a pointer to our first Node of the single linked list? is it because that we avoid any unwanted changes of our main `firstNode` address?

Comment: That is my understanding of Vlad's answer.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen See my appended answer. The second function can be more clear for you.

Comment: It is also possible to combine the interface of the first function with the brevity of the second function by using a variable `no **current = &firstNode;`, using the remaining code from the first function but with `current` in place of `firstNode`, and finally returning `firstNode` like the second function.

Comment: I just read the second version now. It looks like you do a first pass to delete target values at the very head of the list, and then use the additional variable `current` to prevent exhausting `firstNode` while traversing the rest of the list. That's clever, but do you need a loop for the first pass or is it sufficient to just process that first element? I think you can just consider one iteration of your first pass.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen If you have a sequence of duplicated values starting from the head node then you need a loop.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ihave a problem here in the appended answer. in the first one we used another pointer to save the address of the linked list head so the `current` will point to two addresses and then the data. but here i cant get why we make current a double pointer

Comment: @Rosha.R In the first function the parameter is pointer to pointer. In the other two function the parameter is just a pointer.

Comment: Oh now i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One needs a pointer to a pointer to modify the head node given the function, and one should merely loop while current is not null.

```
void* toDEduplicatedlinkedlist(no** firstNode, int target)
{

    no* current = *firstNode;
    no* ptemp = *firstNode;

    while (NULL != current)
    {
        no* temp = NULL;
        if (current->data == target)
        {
            if (current == *firstNode) {
                *firstNode = current->next;
            }
            else {
                ptemp->next = current->next;
            }
            temp = current;
        }
        else {
            ptemp = current;
        }
        current = current->next;
        if(temp != NULL) free(temp); 
    }
    return *firstNode;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response and help. I now understand it.

Comment: @Rosha.R The provided code is incorrect and has undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I now saw how it made error. thank you for reminding.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I see, I freed current before advancing it, I updated the answer to be correct.